# Transform properties preventing hidden backside-visilibility?

Tags: properties, transform

I am just working on a site which combines a backside menu flip a la Eric Arbe with some js-based effects. For some reason the backside of these hover effects ist still visible when turning the backside - though it is in the front container that is supposed to be hidden.

Could the transform properties within the effects prevent the hidden disability?

Answer (score 0):

### This solution depends on the specific CSS and Javascript for your device

- This approach depends on the specific CSS and Javascript compatibility for the device you are running
- The CSS transform properties do not behave the same on all devices and you may have to use a fall-back option if the CSS+Javascript compatibility is not the same as the device where you first tested the effect.